# regex expression help needed

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering if this was possible using Regex.  I would like to exclude all letters (upper and lowercase) and the following 14 characters ! “ & ‘ * + , : ; < = > @ _

The problem is the equal sign.  In the string (which must either be 20 or 37 characters long) that I will be validating, that equal sign must either be in the 17th or 20th position because it is used as a separator in those positions.  So it must check if that equal sign is anywhere other than in the 16th or 20th position (but not both).  The following are some examples:

pass: 1234567890123456=12345678901234567890

pass: 1234567890123456789=12345678901234567

don't pass: 123456=890123456=12345678901234567

don't pass: 1234567890123456=12=45678901234567890

I am having a hard time with the part that I must allow the equal sign in those two positions and not sure if that's possible with Regex.  Adding an if-statement would require substantial code change and regression testing because this function that stores this regex currently is used by many different plug-ins.

Comment: Is there an exact length expectation for this string?

Comment: hello, for the whole string?  Yes, it may either be 20 or 37 characters long.

Comment: if the string is 20 chars long, is the 20th char =?

Comment: yes, that can be one of the possible instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go for

```
^([^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]+|[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]*)$
```

**Explanations :**

1) Start with your allowed char :

`^[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]$`

[^xxx] means all except xxx, where a-z is lower case letters A-Z upper case ones, and your others chars

2) Repeat it 16 times, then =, then others allowed chars ("allowed char" followed by '+' to tell that is repeated 1 to n times)

`^[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]+$`

At this point you'll match your first case, when = is at position 17.

3) Your second case will be

`^[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]*$`

with the last part followed by * instead of + to handle strings that are only 20 chars long and that ends with =

4) just use the (case1|case2) to handle both

`^([^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]+|[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]*)$`

Tested OK with notepad++ and your examples

---

Edit to match exactly 20 or 37 chars

```
^([^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{3}|[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{20}|[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19}=|[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19}=[^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{17})$
```

More readable view with explanation :

```
`
^(                              
                                // 20 chars with = at 17
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16} // 16 allowed chars
    =                           // followed by =
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{3}  // folowed by 3 allowed chars
|                               
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{16} // 37 chars with = at 17   
    =                           
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{20}
|
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19} // 20 chars with = at 20   
    =
|
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{19} // 37 chars with = at 20
    =
    [^a-zA-Z!"&'*+,:;<=>@_]{17}
)$
```

`

Comment: Arf, too slow haha

Comment: one more question, where do I add the portion {20,37} that checks the total string length?

Comment: {20,37} doesn't mean 20 or 37 but 20 to 37, that's not what you want. I would check the length before applying the regex. But if you want to handle this just by regex, you'll have to describe all the possibilities.

Comment: Use a `(?=.{20,37}$)` lookahead after `^` Iif you allow 20  to 37 char input.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant.  thank you.  I tried adding that in the end in place of the asterisk but it doesn't seem to fail the string if I have any other lengths.

Comment: I edited my response to handle only 20 or 37 chars strings.

Comment: I'll just add the suggestion that even when I've had "lists of regexes" in some configuration region, for which individual logic can't be applied, there's usually additional configuration allowed for things like minimum and maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

I've omitted other symbols matching other symbols and just placed the `[^=]`, you should have there code for all allowed symbols except `=`

```
var r = new Regex(@"^(([0-9\:\<\>]{16,16}=(([0-9\:\<\>]{20})|([0-9\:\<\>]{3})))|(^[^=]{19,19}=(([0-9\:\<\>]{17}))?))$");
/*
    @"^(

    ([0-9\:\<\>]{16,16}
    =
    (([0-9\:\<\>]{20})|([0-9\:\<\>]{3})))

    |

    (^[^=]{19,19}
    =
    (([0-9\:\<\>]{17}))?)

    )$"
*/
```

using `{length,length}` you can also specify the overall string length. The `$` in the end and `^` in the beginning are important also.

Comment: Thank you!  I have one quick question, where do incorporate the 14 symbols that I want the string to fail immediately regardless of where they are?  This is what is currently in the code: @"^[0-9\:\<\>]{20,37}$"

Comment: I've updated my answer, it allows exactly 20 or 37. One thing I don't get - if = is on 20'th position than the string will end ion this =

Comment: In fact you really have to specify all possibilities for the second part of the string with | . So it's either 3 and 20 for = on 17th place, and 0 and 17 for = on 20th place

Comment: is there something I'm not doing right?  I'm trying your solution on regexr.com using my string examples and can't get it to work.

Comment: Well you should try it in C#. Cause there are a lot of potential differences in escaping and regexp's are handled slitly differently in different compilers. regexr.com I guess uses perl format. Anyway kipy's last edit is almost the same and better formatted.